# No content elements got displayed on newly added pages after making typo3 multilingual

Tags: typo3, multilingual, realurl

i have got the problem, that i made my typo3 multilingual (german, english) using real url, everything worked fine.
now i added a page and the page got displayed but not it´s content elements.

anyone can help please?

Comment: If you really want help, you need to be more precise: After adding the page, does it work in both languages? Is there no content on both sites? What is your language TypoScript configuration?

Comment: it doesn't work on both languages with real url enabled, calling the page via the id it works in both languages (by using the l parameter). it seems to be a real url problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you don't have the neccessary language (which you have selected in the frontend) version of that page's content?

Comment: no, because it works when i call the page by the id. in both languages. (using the l parameter)